# mysql WHERE '2010-08-24 11:59:59' BETWEEN c.start_date AND c.end_date;

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm currently trying to use this query

```
SELECT 
a.id AS id,
a.item AS item,
c.id AS campaign_id,
DATE(c.start_date) AS START,
DATE(c.end_date) AS END
FROM campaign c LEFT JOIN action_6 a
ON c.id = a.campaign_id WHERE action_id = 6
AND TIMESTAMP('2010-08-24 11:59:59') BETWEEN c.start_date AND c.end_date;
```

however i am getting an empty resultset due to the `AND '2010-08-24 11:59:59' BETWEEN c.start_date AND c.end_date`.

`c.start_date` and `c.end_date` (on the desired row) are `2010-08-23 00:00:00` and `2010-07-29 23:59:59` so it should be returning the row yes?

---

**Edit:**  updated query to show explicit conversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting an empty resultset because the timestamp 2010-08-24 11:59:59 is **not** between 2010-07-29 23:59:59 and 2010-08-23 00:00:00 (see last paragraph if this isn't a typo and you really meant `between 2010-08-23 00:00:00 and 2010-07-29 23:59:59`).

Here are two queries to test this out.
This query returns 0 (False):

```
SELECT '2010-08-24 11:59:59' 
BETWEEN '2010-07-29 23:59:59' AND '2010-08-23 00:00:00'
```

This query returns 1 (True):

```
SELECT '2010-08-24 11:59:59' 
BETWEEN '2010-07-29 23:59:59' AND '2010-08-25 00:00:00'
```

Moreover, the order of the inputs also matters:  you should swap the start and end dates such that the start date precedes the end date.

Comment: ah my mistake, didn't even see it was 07 instead of 08 :) appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that c.start_date and c.end_date are both date type values rather than VARCHARs then '2010-08-24 11:59:59' is a string. You need to convert it to a date

Comment: they are both datetime, but, i tried wrapping them in Date(c.start_date) and Date(c.end_date) and Date('2010-08-24 11:59:59') but i get the same result,